# php OOP - call static method from another class within class

Tags: php, oop, class

I have the following class to another class in my main class.

```
class Products 
{
    public function __get( $key ){
        return trim(functions::mssql_escape_string_rev($this->fields[ $key ]));
    }
}
```

This beings back error:  `Call to undefined method functions::mssql_escape_string_rev()`

Is there something wrong with my syntax or can this not be done?

Below is code used to autoload classes, this works for everything else so I know there is nothign wrong with the code.  It just doesnt seem to initiate within the class.

```
// autoloader function called when we try to instantiate a class but haven't included the file
function __autoload($resource_name){

    $resource_name = trim($resource_name);

    try { 

        $filepath = CLASS_PATH."/class.".$resource_name.".inc.php";

        if(@!include($filepath)){

            throw new Exception('');
        }

    } catch(Exception $e) {

        exit("Could not find the required file: ".$resource_name);

    }
}
```

**********EDIT************
Please ignore this, I made a stupid mistake and included the functions::mssql_escape_string_rev twice.  Sorry for timewasting..

Comment: "functions" is your another class?

Comment: Does `functions` is a class you defined ?

Comment: yes, it is a class full of static functions.

Comment: I use an autoloader so I do not have to include each class.  This works when I am not wihin another class.

Comment: You have some error somewhere else because the above should just work. http://codepad.org/uJTjccRY

Comment: You should probably post the code for the "functions" class, so we can better understand the problem.

Comment: @LeeTee Your functions class sounds like an architecture smell to me.

Comment: Are you aware that there is a huge difference between *object oriented programming* and *class oriented programming*. Instead of creating a static class, you should just use simple function, wrapped in a namespace. Additionally: use PDO.

Comment: @PiTheNumber It does not really make sense to have all your functions in a class called `functions`.

Comment: I know you should not do that. But I needed some arguments for another discussion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As the error says the problem is that `functions::mssql_escape_string_rev()` is not defined.

Since we can't see what you think is the definition we can not really help you.

For me it looks like the call should be `Functions::mysql_escape_string_rev()` with capital `F` and `mysql`.

**Update**

Calling static functions from another class works normally: http://codepad.org/wrfm5X7j

Maybe you are calling mysql_escape_string_rev before you included the functions class.

Comment: Why shouldn't he be using mssql? But I agree with the capital `F`.

Comment: Oh, he could. But since we don't know, I can only guess and mysql is more likely then mssql.

Comment: I am using mssql not mysql.  Also my class functions is with a small f not capital.  Therefore my method title and class title is correct  PS.  I'm a she ;0)

Comment: Do I need to add define functions within my class?  I really am at a loss to see whats wrong here..

Comment: oh, sorry about that! How about posting the declaration of `functions::mssql_escape_string_rev()`?

Comment: Ive checked this also and is defo classed after the functions class is included

Comment: Hm... maybe class_exists and method_exists can help you debug.